# A function that has exactly two values on $I_n=(0,1/n)$ for all n.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I_n=(0,\frac1n)$ be a sequence of interval.

**Is it possible for a real function $f$ to have exactly two values on $I_n$ for all $n$?**

My try. Suppose the two values are zero and one. We have $f(I_m)$ has two values, $f(I_{m+1})$ also has two values. So $f(I_m\setminus I_{m+1})$ must be constant. WLOG let $f(I_m\setminus I_{m+1})=0$. By induction, $f(I_1\setminus I_n)=0$ for all $n$.

Now I want to take the limit $n\to\infty$. However, $f(I_1\setminus I_n)$ might diverge. Stuck here.

Comment: $f(x)=0$ for $x$ rational and $f(x)=1$ for $x$ irrational

Comment: @geetha290krm That's so smart!

Comment: What do you mean "have exactly two values"?  I'd have thought you meant that $f(x)$ only took two values in the given domain, but you appear to mean something else.

Comment: @lulu The value of a function, given the value(s) assigned to its argument(s), is the quantity assumed by the function for these argument values. Wikipedia-Value

Comment: Ok...but what makes you think that $f$ would have to be constant on the complement of $I_{m+1}$ in $I_m$?

Comment: @lulu Bad math skills of mine ....